# Connecting to MS SQL DB from Java Netbeans

Tags: java

How do I connect to MS Sql database using Java.

I am using the jtds jdbc driver but keep getting the "No Suitable Driver" error. I have checked the jdbc URL and it conforms to the URL format specified in the documentation.

I am running on JRE6.

Comment: show us the code you are using..

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually loaded the driver class?

Example for MySQL:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

before connecting:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "pw");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a solution. One can use the microsoft SQL server jdbc driver

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
      String url = " jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://serverjag:1433";
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","");
```